# Gazebo object rearrangements

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I often need to change between different object arrangements within Gazebo (within ROS).

What is a better practice? or more stable?

Change object pose through some ROS service?

Or, is it better to create a world file for each arrangement and relaunch Gazebo?

Or, does this not matter?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1094/gazebo-object-rearrangements/) by [jys](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/141/jys/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's a bit more stable to create multiple world files and relaunch Gazebo.

However, you should be able to dynamically reposition the objects without any problems.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0